# Is it possible to flash IPMI controller firmware from remote?

Tags: remote, ipmi

I just wondered if someone could install malicious firmware from remote on IPMI controllers (similar to a rootkit)? Is something like that possible? I though about installing a keylogger sending summaries over SNMP. I know normally IPMIs are in different subnets, protected by passwords,.. but commit that the attacker has knowledge to overcome those barriers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last Defcon, [Jonathan Brossard](https://twitter.com/endrazine) gave a talk regarding hardware backdooring, and how it is possible to install a rootkit into a bios or a NIC rom (remotely).

They were also able to reverse engineer the [kon-boot](http://www.piotrbania.com/all/kon-boot/) payload and include it in their malware.

The slides can be found [here](http://korben.info/wp-content/uploads/defcon/SpeakerPresentations/Brossard/DEFCON-20-Brossard-Hardware-Backdooring-is-Practical.pdf), and the article is [here](http://korben.info/wp-content/uploads/defcon/SpeakerPresentations/Brossard/DEFCON-20-Brossard-Hardware-Backdooring-is-Practical-WP.pdf).

So yes, I'd say it's possible to get access to IPMI and maybe install a rootkit on it...